# OneDrive (SkyDrive) REST API does not work with Unicode

Tags: c#, api, rest, unicode, onedrive

I am using the OneDrive REST API from a C# desktop application and I find that it is not coping with Unicode characters.

When I get a folder listing via the REST API that contains names with foreign characters they are being mangled.

When I look online using the OneDrive web interface the foreign chars are correct.

Even using the test program "Live Connect API Explorer" in LiveSDK-for-Windows-master.zip from Microsoft the chars are mangled.

Is Unicode not supported by the REST API?

Comment: The name should came across the wire as a UTF-8 encoded string. If you decode the raw bytes as such do you get the value you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Unicode is supported. Can you share one of the unicode strings that's getting mangled as well as how it's getting mangled? I tried the API Explorer with some unicode filenames and it was able to render them:

```
{
  "id": "file.abc123.abc123!7735",
  "name": "माधुरी दीक्षित.jpg", 
  ...
}
```

Note that the API returns unicode characters unencoded in the JSON response. Is it possible that something else in your processing pipeline can't handle that? Or maybe your app isn't using a font can display the characters?